# Load some database data in memory when Express loads

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a simple way to store some data in Express? For example, I would like to load all the API keys (from the PostgreSQL database) in memory when the server starts so I don't have to query PostgreSQL for each single request to my API.

I thought about using `global.api_keys`, but as globals should always be avoided (right?) I'm pretty sure there's a better solution.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.set(name, value)` for that.

Then, you can get the setted value with `app.get(name)`.

HTH

Reference: http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html